# Yandex Map for iOS is available to work with OverlayView

Tags: ios, google-maps, yandex

I have some problem with creation route in map.

For route in google maps I use MKPolylineView, but in yandex maps i dont see it...

How create route in yandex map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create route in iOS yandex map.

You can use this [superstructure](https://github.com/antigp/YandexMapKitRoute)

1 You must add "Yandex MapKit Route" to your project folder with all its files.

2 In your project use method (as sample):

```
[YandexMapKitRoute showRouteOnMap:self.mapView From:YMKMapCoordinateMake(55.837064,37.487895) To:YMKMapCoordinateMake(55.695618,37.657496)];
```

3 And scroll to it

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:YMKMapCoordinateMake(55.754219,37.622478)
                      atZoomLevel:10
                         animated:NO];
```